# Best way to manage folder access with laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

In my domain when i reach this url www.mydomain.com/app/ It obviously load the app content and list all folders and files presents inside so anyone can access to my controller files.php

I believed that laravel provided these actions but it didn't.

I think I should edit my apache conf or add .htaccess in each folder or redirect the user with laravel while accessing these "routes".

But I don't think that one of these solution is good. May i know which is better ?

Comment: Only the contents of your laravel's public folder should be in your public_html on your domain, the rest should be outside of it, that's the point.

Comment: I'm at dreamhost and my root directory is such like "/home/www/" in www i have all the laravel architecture folder and file and mine obviously

Comment: then you have to keep the contents of the public folder (not the folder, just all the contents in www) and the rest folders one level up under /home/app home/vendor etc

Comment: Ok that's the solution, it works, I'm so stupid ! thx Dimitris.

Comment: I will add an answer and mark it as answered so other can get help from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep the contents of the public folder (not the folder, just all the contents in www or public_html) and the rest folders one level up under /home/app, home/vendor etc

Comment: Thanks again, I can not vote up yet but I'll do when i'll can

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to move the contents of the `app` folder above your root `www` directory, you can simply use this in your `.htaccess` to force all requests to your `public` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have FTP account where you can see your actual "root" folder ?

it might be something like:

/home/public_html
or
/home/httpdocs

If so then Laravel should reside in the /home/... folder.

and Laravel's public folder contents should be copied into public_html (or httpdocs)

If you only have access to the root folder then edit the file /bootstrap/paths.php

Change the following:

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

**TO:**

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../',
```

Comment: Ok so I did that, all my files which where in my public folder are in my root folder.
I did that because there was "public" in my URL